# meteor poll on demand without subscribing

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there an easy way to use the meteor api to poll on demand without the overhead of realtime subscriptions? I don't want to use a rest api, i just want to get it from ddp but without keeping the subscription. Some data just doesn't need to be that real time. Thanks!

Comment: Please describe in more detail your use-case...

Comment: Your best bet might be to do a `subscribe` with a `stop()` call in the callback.

Comment: You could use Meteor.call to fetch the data in json form and use it directly. If you want it in collection form you could do @ChristianFritz's way too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.meteor.com/#find section of Meteor docs:

> Cursors are a reactive data source. The first time you retrieve a
>   cursor's documents with fetch, map, or forEach inside a reactive
>   computation (eg, a template or autorun), Meteor will register a
>   dependency on the underlying data. Any change to the collection that
>   changes the documents in a cursor will trigger a recomputation. To
>   disable this behavior, pass `{reactive: false}` as an option to find.

Comment: That sounds just client side, will that end the subscription?

Comment: As the docs state, this is an *anywhere* api. you just publish with this in your find statement, then the client will not be sent any updates.